# centering a the inner navbar in a dual-collapse navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following navbar:
Its almost where i need it to be, iy is constructed as brand, center navbar and left navbar. 
What would be the bootstrap way to make the center part truly center.

thank you in advance

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="mr-auto order-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 mx-auto order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#menu">aa</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroller" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show" href="#specials">bb</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#events">cc</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#aaa">aaa</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#bbb">bbb</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the brand container `w-100` too...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="w-100 order-0">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">Brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 mx-auto order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#menu">aa</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroller" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show" href="#specials">bb</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#events">cc</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#aaa">aaa</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroller" href="#bbb">bbb</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/TfJUc5gMNN)